# Get output parameter value

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF in my MVC project. In my project I need to use stored procedures. My problem is to use output parameter with stored procedures. I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you create your entity model, you should make sure that you include stored procedures. Then, create Function Imports for them:

1. Open your Entity Model in Visual Studio
2. The Model Browser should open on the right side of the screen
3. In the Model Browser, you need to select the stored procedure and click *Add Function Import* to create the function for the stored procedure.
4. A dialog box will open to select the stored procedure and return type

That's it. Now you can use that in code.

```
using (MyEntities myContext = new MyEntities ())            
{                
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter output = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("OutputParameterName", typeof(int));                
   myContext.GetCustomerCount(output);                
   Console.WriteLine(output.Value);            
}
```

Comment: I'd solved similar pattern in my code and I noticed that Value property of output parameter is filled after accessing output result set.

Answer (score 15):

Modified Answer for Entity Framework 6.x / VS 2015 - notice the namespace change:

```
using (MyEntities myContext = new MyEntities ())            
{                
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter output = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("OutputParameterName", typeof(int));                
   myContext.GetCustomerCount(output);                
   Console.WriteLine(output.Value);            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of doing it using Entity framework

```
YourDB db = new YourDB();
public double GetCategoryYearly(double Param1, double Param2, double Param3)
{
    System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter OutputParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("SPOutputParam", typeof(double));
    var objStoredProc = db.YourStoredProc(Param1, Param2, Param3, OutputParam).First();
    return Convert.ToDouble(OutputParam.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

using (Entities context = new Entities())
{

   ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("varName", typeof(int));

   context.storedProcedure(output);

   Console.WriteLine(output.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `Entities` is supposed to be capitalized.